# "Download additional server adapters" missing from Eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I want to set up glassfish server (Java EE 8) downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html, but I don't see glassfish nor do I see "Download additional server adapters" when I try to add a new server to a project.

What should I do now?

[image]

Comment: what version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For seeing them you must have installed  [**Eclipse WTP**](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

Or you can also download the [glassfish tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools) (you can also download them from eclipse marketplace)